# Macro to edit the multiple links in excel file

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am working on excel workbook which contains 30 files linked to this workbook. every month these 30 files are renamed on the basis of the current month and saved in current month folder. Right now I have to manually update the workbook with these 30 links. Can we do this with the help of a macro to automatically update these 30 links by replacing the old links.

Comment: Yes, its possible but I will not give you code because this is not how Stack Overflow works. You need to demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved, show your attempts at solving the problem etc. See [**Help Centre**](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to get started

Answer (score 0):

mehow is correct; the only possible answer to your question is "Yes it is possible."

This is not an answer, it is just to demonstrate that it is possible and to give you a start.  Your question will almost certainly be closed or put on hold.  Try creating a macro based on my code then come back with specific problems if necessary.

My extensions are "xls" because I still use Excel 2003 on the computer used to create this answer.  If you are using a later version, your extensions will be "xlsm" or "xlsx".

I have three workbooks: "Master", "Dept 1", "Dept 2".  I have used variables to hold the names of workbooks "Dept 1" and "Dept 2".  You may need to include the paths of the source workbooks within the names.  I have used variables so the names can be changed easily.  Perhaps they can be set to an expression based on the current month:

```
Wbook1 = Format(Now(), "yyyy-mmmm") & ".xls"
```

would set Wbook1 to "2013-December.xls".

```
Dim LastMonth As Date
LastMonth = DateSerial(Year(Now()), Month(Now()) - 1, Day(Now()))
Wbook1 = Format(LastMonth, "yyyy-mmmm") & ".xls"
```

would set Wbook1 to "2013-November.xls".

The follow macro sets two cells within "Sheet1" of the current workbook ("Master") to the value of cells within the other workbooks.

```
Sub Try()

  Dim Wbook1 As String
  Dim Wbook2 As String

  Wbook1 = "Dept 1.xls"
  Wbook2 = "Dept 2.xls"

  With Worksheets("Sheet1")

    .Range("H18").Value = "='[" & Wbook1 & "]Sheet2'!D6"
    .Range("H19").Value = "='[" & Wbook2 & "]Sheet3'!D9"

  End With

End Sub
```

**Response to first comment**

The vague description of what you are attempting means I have given you as much information as I can.  Do not attempt a better description because this is not the type of site where someone will create a complete solution in response to a detailed specification.

The macro I provided shows how to create links that copy values in from two other workbooks.  I have used the simpliest code I could think of so you should be able to adapt it to your needs.

Based on my code, create a macro in your master workbook that creates a single link from one of your source workbooks.  I have simply copied values in from the source workbooks.  Perhaps you want an expression that combines two or more values.  Try to create that expression.  Perhaps you want to search the master workbook for formulae that contain "[2013-November.xls]" and replace every occurrance with "[2013-December.xls]".  Try that.

Break your requirement down into tiny steps and try to solve it one step at a time.  If your macro does not do what you expect and you cannot determine why, come back with that macro, a description of what it does and what you want it to do and you will probably get an instance answer because that is what this site specialises in.

Comment: Thanks Tony and Mehow. I am really new to macros and would really appreciate if you guys can help me with this stuff in more details.

Comment: @user3115226.  I have added a response to your comment to my answer.